# Can I get vlc 2.0 Mac skin for ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, customization, vlc

I'm not a big fan of Mac but the new vlc 2.0 for Mac looks seriously good. Both windows and ubuntu versions suck. So how can I/we make it look good ?

[image: mac vlc]

[image: ubuntu vlc]

Comment: i was about to create this question... the vlc skins are nasty: they lose 70% of the default skin's features. the mac theme is not a skin but the default appearance and it looks great compared to the default one of win and linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unlike mac you can apply diffrent theme for vlc in linux and windows
[theme are available here](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/skins.php)

**How to use these skins?**

Skins do not work on Mac OS X!
Put the downloaded VLT files in the following folder:

```
On Windows: the skins folder in the VLC installation directory (e.g. C:\Program Files\VLC\skins)
On Linux/Unix: ~/.local/share/vlc/skins2
```

Then open your VLC settings and change your interface from native to skins. You can choose your desired skin already there or change it when you are in the skins mode by rightclicking somewhere on the skin and going to Interface>Choose Skin.
VLC needs to be restarted to change to skins mode.

Comment: I can't find the theme I want. The current mac 2.0 theme.

Comment: That theme is  available for mac only
developers may create equallent skin for linux/windows versions of vlc

Comment: Yeah ,If you are interseted use pix maps from vlc for macs source code , and use it in your new theme

Comment: i was about to ask the same question on askubuntu. sadly this is no answer. the mac appearance is not a skin but a greatly improved default interface of vlc, while the win and linux skins that are praised here look like 1995 and lose most of the default features. i mean the default interface is far better then those skins. in mac you now have all the features and better looks. saying to people "go and create one yourself if you don't like what it's there" is not an answer, but it's a 'NO' answer. a 'YES' answer would be just providing the full-featured good-looking vlc skin. :))

Comment: mac users also can use themes in fact : like [this](http://k-profiler.deviantart.com/art/Minimal-Theme-for-VLC-2-0-9-Mac-391256333) one